# Problem with EF Migration in Docker Container

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

I have a problem with migrating my database to a docker container.

During said migration I get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.'
```

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'


networks:
    backend:


services:
  libraryapi:
    container_name: Library-Api
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}libraryapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
        - backend
    ports:
        - 8001:80
        - 8003:443
    environment:
        - DB_HOST=librarydb
        - DB_NAME=Library
        - DB_SA_PASSWORD=q6ZOc32APBvTelKK6nlb0g31rVcWTq
  librarydb:
     container_name : Library-DB
     image : mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
     networks:
        - backend
     ports:
        - 8002:1433
     environment:
        - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=q6ZOc32APBvTelKK6nlb0g31rVcWTq
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 80

EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src

COPY \["LibraryAPI.csproj", "."\]

RUN dotnet restore "./LibraryAPI.csproj"

COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/."

RUN dotnet build "LibraryAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish

RUN dotnet publish "LibraryAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT \["dotnet", "LibraryAPI.dll"\]
```

docker-compose-override (Whatever it is):

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  libraryapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

I am starting my application via Docker Compose project in Visual Studio

I have already deleted the container, docker cache, and rebuilt the project multiple times. I have no more ideas what I can do.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this problem is database-specific rather than Docker-related. Please take a look into the DB migration. It says you need to **drop the column with identity property** and recreate it to apply the migration. Your SQL code is wrong at the moment.